# Set fastcgi_param on specific URL in nginx

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

I am want to set a PHP_VALUE using fastcgi_param on one specific URL.

My nginx config looks like that:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name test.domain;

    root /var/www/test;

    index index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;

        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
}
```

I want to exclusively set something like that:

```
location /admin {
    fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "newrelic.enabled=false";
}
```

Where exactly do I have to put it? I've tried pasting it before & after existing location blocks but it returns 404 on that URL after I do it.

Additionaly this location /admin should catch everything what's after that URL. I assume it already does, but I am not sure if it should look like /admin/(.*)$.

Please help!